# In 2009, where were Bitcoin source codes stored?

Tags: source-code

Now I can see the Bitcoin Core source code in Github but I wonder where the original source code of Bitcoin were stored back in 2009? Was it managed under SVN? How did contributors or programmers work together back then?

Thanks,
Pil

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**2008**
We don't know if Satoshi Nakamoto is an individual or a group, but [Satoshi Nakamoto asked for professional crypto geeks to review his project in 2008](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=382374.0).
The [original source files were therefore distributed privately through email](https://github.com/benjyz/bitcoinArchive).

**2009**
Unsure if Satoshi Nakamoto used any kind of source control before the source codes were available to the public. You probably have to ask the developers that were involved.
[First available on Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/).
[Initial commits on GitHub](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commits/master?after=d48ab83f00538a5135b2c448809260a9d46ca31c%2015635) were converted from svn on Sourceforge.

Comment: The repository does still exist? https://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/

Comment: You know what, you are actually right. I got 404-Error earlier, but seems like it is up after all. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. It helped much.

Comment: The source code was originally hosted in a rar file on Bitcoin.org. It did not use any Source Control Management. Later, when more people began working on it, one of the earliest developers, Sirius, moved everything to SVN on Sourceforge. That was later moved to the current Github repository and switched to using Git.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Chak's answer, I was able to find the (unofficial) github repo hosting https://github.com/benjyz/bitcoinArchive which contains the original bitcoin source code. For those who are interested in review the source code in git, this will help.

You may find [Bitcoin v0.1 released](http://www.metzdowd.com/pipermail/cryptography/2009-January/014994.html) announcement  by Satoshi Nakamoto and [Bitcoin v0.1 source code](https://github.com/benjyz/bitcoinArchive/tree/master/bitcoin0.1)  hosted in github interesting.

Comment: That is not "the github repo" but rather **a** github repo hosting what they claim is the original source code.